# How to identify a sequence in C

Tags: c

I would like to ask how to identify a sequence in C for example AAAAA & ddddd the   sequence is all of the inputted characters must be the same.. How is it possible to achieve that? Do I need to use char ? Here is what i had try

```
 #include<stdio.h>

int main() {
   char ch;


   scanf("%cccc", &ch);

   if (ch = 'c')
      printf(&ch);
   else
      printf("Character is Not the same sequence");

   return (0);
}
```

Comment: `prinf` requires a string argument. A string is a zero-terminated array of characters. `printf(&ch)` doesn't meet that requirement. `scanf("%cccc", &ch)` scans for a character followed by three letter 'c's.

Comment: Your if statement is assigning 'c' to ch, use if (ch == 'c') but you can't use it to compare strings only single characters.  You need to store the input as a string and use strcmp() or a similar function.

Comment: did i start off with the wrong function?

Answer (score 1):

To compare two characters:

```
char a = 'a';
char b = 'b';
return a == b; // this compares integer values of two characters
               // and returns 1/0 if they do match/do not match
```

To compare strings:

```
char str1 = "AAAAA";
char str2 = "aaaaa";
return strcmp(str1, str2);
```

man strcmp(3):

> The  strcmp() function compares the two strings s1 and s2.  It returns
>   an integer less than, equal
>          to, or greater than zero if s1 is found, respectively, to be less than, to match,  or  be  greater
>          than s2.
>   The  strncmp()  function is similar, except it compares the only first (at most) n bytes of s1 and
>          s2.

---

Your code contains few bugs. `%c` format is for scanning single character, use `%s` for strings. Here:

```
if (ch = 'c')
```

you assigned `'c'` to `ch`, not what you wanted. Use `==` in C for comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

I would try this:

- Accept a string as input (instead of a character)
- Set up a loop to walk through the string, character by character
- Your first character will be the "good" value
- If at any time, you encounter a different character, fail out of the loop
- If you reach the end of the string without failing, you succeed

Answer (score 0):

Create a Macro for the pattern you want to find. typecast your input to the size of the pattern you want to recognise. Subtract both. If 0 pattern matched. Else,shift right 1 bit and repeat. Example, Pattern to find #define wPAT 0x1234. Input=> U32 dwInput=0x12345678. Result= (U16)dwInput - wPAT . If 0,pattern found. Else, dwInput>>1 and repeat Result= (U16)dwInput - wPAT. Repeat 16 times to find if pattern is present or not